# .htaccess not working as expected, 404 error on screen

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, .htaccess

Problem: I want the url to look like the one StackOverflow has developed their user friendly url. But this code in my htaccess is not giving the expected output, and I don't know what's wrong.

Any suggestions on how do I fix this?

How I want my url to look like: **localhost/project/item/item-name/item-code/12345/item-number/12345**

Error which appears on screen: **error 404 page not found**
 [link to the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQ196.png)

EDIT: this is my htaccess code currently

```
Options +FollowSymlinks RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^product/? ([^/])/?([^/])/?([^/]*)
product.php?productname=$productname&productcode=$productcode&productid=$productid
```

Comment: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: thanks for the comment!! but the output pn the browser is still the same

Comment: It is better to post your code instead of an image of it. That way anyone who is looking to help can get a fast copy to help out.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion!! comment added please check

Comment: @sid : actually, it should have been an update, neither a comment, nor an answer :) edited it, you may consider deleting your 'answer'

Comment: thanks!! will keep it in mind next time. bdw any suggestion on the question?

Answer (score 0):

this is my htaccess code currently

Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^product/? ([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*) product.php?productname=$productname&productcode=$productcode&productid=$productid

Comment: please consider updating your question, when you add some code, it's actually much easier for people to see all at one glance ;)